# How to find commas not preceded or followed by another comma?

Tags: regex, duplicates, notepad++, regex-lookarounds

I have a text file with thousands of lines like these:

```
8/15/2016,,Amazon,,15.93 ;most are like this
8/24/2016,,Google,18.73  ;a few are like this - one comma only
8/26/2016,,Ebay,,60.2    ;
```

Most of the lines have two commas followed by some text, followed by another two commas, followed by a numeric value. Just a few dozen of the lines are like the second line. They have only one comma before the numeric value.

I'm trying to use Regex to find these few dozen lines. I'm not using a programming language, just Notepad++. My problem is that the regex I've come up with so far catches both. I've been experimenting at regex101.com

I got something like this: `2016,,.+?,[0-9]`

I thought that would mean "Find 2016,, followed by any number of characters until you find a comma followed by a numeric digit," but it finds every line, whether it has one or two commas (or more, as I found out when I added some to see what happened).

I read that regex searched "greedily," but I thought the question mark after `.+` made the search stop at the first occurrence.

I even tried `2016,,.+?,{1}[0-9]` thinking the `{1}` would mean "just one," but no, that doesn't work either.

Comment: @mickmackusa yup, as much as I try to explain, as an expert I have to contend with a process where the poster doesn't know the difference and is swayed by glamorous highlighting / indenting and un-needed information, as opposed to honed facts. In reality, my 1900 or so answers are overshadowed by my some 5000 comments. But, I'm here as an educator, not anything else. And I would genuinely like people to learn regex the right way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because the `.+?` of `2016,,.+?,[0-9]` excludes only the last comma:

```
           ▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼
8/15/2016,,Amazon,,,,15.93
```

Hey, it means *any* character, doesn't it?

Code Different's answer is fine, though here are some alternatives:

• Using [negated characters class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html):

```
2016,,[^,]+,[0-9]
```

• Using [negative lookahead/lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) (caution, some regex engines don't support them, though Notepad++ does, still lookbehinds have to be fixed-length):

```
(?<!,),(?!,)
```

Comment: The best pattern (discounting the ultra-literal `2016...` pattern) is Gras Double's "look-both-ways" pattern `(?<!,),(?!,)` this will match only the single comma in just **54** steps -- no capture group needed to "Replace With" `,,`.  Using negated character classes, as CodeDifferent has posted will take **135** steps -- worse if you want to do a replace because then you need a capture group which ramps the steps up to **200**.  For the record, `.*[^,](,)[^,].*` will take **194** steps.

Comment: Thank you! Can you clarify this? I know `.+` means one or more of any character, and I know Regex search usually grabs as much as possible, so `.+,` mean up to the last comma in the line, not the first, but I thought adding the `?` made the search stop as soon as it was satisfied, which would have been at the first comma. Where am I going wrong with my understanding? Thanks.

Comment: It doesn't mean "stop asap" but "eat the less possible, **still being matching**". The `.+?` **has** to grab all the commas (less one), because the `,[0-9]` grabs only one.

Comment: Saved me an hour of relearning how negative assertions work.
I was looking for unescaped quotes in CSV (not preceeded/followed by comma), and ended up with this RE, based on above:  ^ | ((?<!,)"(?!(,|$))).  I had to watch out for lines starting/ending with quote, and then Notepad ++ would not accept (?<?!(^|,)) to check for quote not at start of line.

Comment: @BobHy Yeah, I have stated this at the end of my answer. It's a Notepad++ limitation. You may try juxtaposing assertions, like this: `(?<!,)(?<!^)"(?!,)(?!$)`. That's a trick I often use when I have an assertion that Notepad++ doesn't support.

Answer (score 1):

You can try a comma that is not preceded, nor followed by another comma:

```
[^,],[^,]
```

Add `.*` to the start and end if you want to capture the whole line. [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/qXLBHA/1)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select the lines containing only one comma you can use this

```
.*[^,],[^,].*
```

But if you want to replace the commas with double commas or biceversa, you can

ctrl+f > , >find all > supr > ,, (or ,)

Answer (score 0):

If you use negative assertions to find a single comma,
it is much faster to have the assertions *after* the literal comma.

Putting a negative assertion first in a regex adds a 6x overhead (in this case)
as compared to finding the literal first, then checking with assertions.

This is because it has to run the *assertion* on the stack for every
character position as opposed to just finding the literal first.

Good = `,(?!,)(?<!,,)`
Bad = `(?<!,),(?!,)`

Comparison

Target duplicated string 29 times.

```
8/15/2016,,Amazon,,15.93 ;most are like this
8/24/2016,,Google,18.73  ;a few are like this - one comma only
8/26/2016,,Ebay,,60.2    ;
...
8/15/2016,,Amazon,,15.93 ;most are like this
8/24/2016,,Google,18.73  ;a few are like this - one comma only
8/26/2016,,Ebay,,60.2    ;
... (29 times total)
```

Benchmark

```
Regex1:   ,(?!,)(?<!,,)
Options:  < none >
Completed iterations:   50  /  50     ( x 1000 )
Matches found per iteration:   29
Elapsed Time:    5.92 s,   5919.16 ms,   5919161 µs


Regex2:   (?<!,),(?!,)
Options:  < none >
Completed iterations:   50  /  50     ( x 1000 )
Matches found per iteration:   29
Elapsed Time:    36.81 s,   36806.16 ms,   36806159 µs
```

Comment: This is an interesting alternative, however... the steps from Gras Double's pattern are always fewer than your pattern's.  What seems to be considerably variable is the elapsed time for individual tests.  Please see these test results that speak against your benchmark.  http://imgur.com/a/wxYLy Truth is, the elapsed time is inconsistent, but the steps is always reliable.  There seem to be other factors that impact elapsed time.

Comment: @mickmackusa - **Part 1:** Yeah, there are a lot of factors involved here. I didn't want to go this deep into it, but here goes. Given the two regex under consideration, consider two samples, S1 = _all comas_. S2 = _all letters_ to be used for each regex.  Both PCRE and Perl take roughly 0 steps for _S1_. PCRE, and Perl do extreme optimizations. If it doesn't find a comma, in the target, it won't process regex instructions. Therefore, any benchmark with either of these is meaningless, you get no performance info. Moving on to Python, a more accurate profile can be gleaned.

Comment: @mickmackusa - **Part 2:** (Python) If you use S2 (letters) with the two regex, you can see that `(?<!,),(?!,)` uses 2x more steps, and %30 more time. The difference is this one's assertion is satisfied every time and it has to check for the literal `,`past it. When the table is reversed using S2 (commas), almost the inverse is true, not quite as bad though with `,(?!,)(?<!,,)`. Somewhere in the middle is a break even point. But I don't often see an equal number of comma's vs. non-comma's.